# Kinect v2 Save/Load MultiSourceFrames

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I would like to know if there is a way to save MultiSourceFrames to disk in such a way that I can load them up to use later.

The reason for this is because I have far too much processing to do on each frame to reasonably perform this live. I have no need to process the frames in real time so, I would like to find a way to save a number of frames to disk (or even to memory?) and perform my processing afterwards.

So far, I have tried storing these in a  `List<MultiSourceFrame>` but, for each frame, I find that I can't then acquire the ColourFrame component (for example), presumably because the whole object structure is not saved.

**Potential Solution Idea?**

I know that Kinect Studio is able to save .xed files but I really need to be able to do this from code. Moreover, I don't know whether I can turn the .xed file back into a collection of MultiSourceFrames.

I'd be really grateful if anyone can help me out with this problem! I promise to upvote/accept helpful answers!

Comment: You can't just save the `MultiSourceFrame` object. Instead, you should extract the (raw) data you need from the frames and save that.

Comment: I have decided to save the frames later down the line after processing them with the Kinect SDK. Basically this means that all my image processing happens after the fact but I only need to store images as a byte array. If you had written your comment as an answer, I would have accepted it!

Comment: well...in that case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just save the `MultiSourceFrame` object. Instead, you should extract the (raw) data you need from the frames and save that.